# Encrypt/Decrypt user data in django python

Tags: python, django, encryption, cryptography

I'm working on a project, and the client wants to encrypt the users' data and decrypt those when we have to get it from the DB (so the data are encrypted into the DB).

I'm using Django 1.8 and python 3.5.
The user datas are `CharFields`, `IntegerFields`, `EmailFields`, `DateFields`, etc...

I think the best way to do that is to encrypt the data into the user model `save()` method, make a custom Manager that will do the query set and decrypt the object.

What do you think about that? What encrypt/decrypt library should I use? Is there a better way to do this? Have you some tips / or already do that in a Django project?

Thanks for your answers! :)

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to encrypt the database (who has access to the database anyway?) but have a look at https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields

Comment: It's more by security, and in legal point of view. The application use medical patient datas. So we have to secure and encrypt.

Yeah i know this library but after the encryption you can't use it in django orm (to query on it for exemple...).

Comment: It won't be possible to query or sort unless the encryption is directly supported by the database engine with any method.

Comment: Hum ok, so there is no way to do that, i have to let the data decrypted in the database... thanks for the answer !

Comment: Some engines such as MS SQL server support encryption at the db level. Maybe you should research that option.